# Navigation dropdown not appear above the HTML select option dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

My application have two types of dropdown. Both placed on each other.

My custom list dropdown option have higher z-index but still it will appear behind second dropdown option which is common HTML option dropdown.

I want my first dropdown should always appear at front.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: post your code please. also, note that z-index only works for elements with a set positioning

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works for elements which have their position set.

in the following example, 4 divs, 2 on top of other 2, note how the yellow div's z-index works while the blue one's doesnt, because the yellow has its position set and the blue doesnt:

```css
div{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
.red{
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
}
.blue{
    background:blue;
    z-index:2;
}
.green{
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
}
.yellow{
    background:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
```

here is the same in a fiddle, so you can play around with the css and see the difference:

<kbd>[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/fg6r3xz0/)</kbd>

**UPDATE:**

following your fiddle, i have bad news and good news:

**bad news:** the html dropdown option list is rendered by the browser liek a context menu, and will always appear above all other elements, and you cannot change that.

**good news:**, you can create your own custom dropdown list and make it appear behind the menu. luckily, jQuery UI does exactly that using [jQuery SelectMenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)

you can download jquery [**Here**](http://jquery.com/download/), and customize your own jquery UI theme [**Here**](http://jqueryui.com/download/) (or use the online links from the example below)

```js
$(function(){
    $("#divisiondrpdwn").selectmenu();
});
```

```css
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.Nav2 ul.Main {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.Nav2 ul.Main li {
    float:left;
}
.Nav2 ul.Main li> a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 15px;
    color:#00f;
    background:url(sprite.png) no-repeat right 8px #ff0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
    height:18px;
    line-height:18px;
}
/*-----Hover-----*/
 .Nav2 ul.Main li a:hover {
    background:#fc0;
    color:#000;
}
.Nav2 ul.Main li:last-child a, ul.Dropdown a {
    background-image:none;
}
.Nav2 ul.Dropdown {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 9.2em;
    z-index: 1020;
}
.Nav2 ul.Dropdown li {
    text-decoration:none;
    clear:both
}
.Nav2 ul.Dropdown li> a {
    background-image:none;
    display:none;
    padding: 5px 24px;
}
.Nav2 ul.Main li:hover ul.Dropdown li> a {
    display:block;
}
.Nav2 ul.Dropdown li> a:hover {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="Nav2">
    <ul class="Main">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallary</a>

            <ul class="Dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>

            <ul class="Dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select id="divisiondrpdwn">
        <option value="99">changes</option>
        <option value="6">CPS</option>
        <option value="106">Layout-8</option>
        <option value="284">Layout-9</option>
        <option value="291">Mixed Layouts</option>
        <option value="41">Naya Hai Wah</option>
        <option value="103">New Layout</option>
        <option value="36">Ram</option>
        <option value="39">Try</option>
        <option value="37">xxx</option>
        <option value="273">YD-ID</option>
        <option value="274" selected="">YD-ID1</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I have attached screenshot for appeared issue.

Comment: Above navigation menu hide behind below dropdown option list.

Comment: the screenshot makes no difference, my answer still applies. if your issue is different, then please post your code, a picture is not enough for debugging.

Comment: I need to show that navigation option menu above below drop-down option.

Comment: I applied same functionality and gave higher z-index:99999 and also gave position to respected drop-down option.

Comment: please post your code. there could be dozens of reasons for your issue, it is almost not possible to help you by looking at a picture.

Comment: I found that HTML standard select option dropdown have more z-index value than any custom dropdown option panel.

Comment: if you are not going to post the relevant code, im afraid i will not be able to assist you further.

Comment: I have prepared one demo for same issue. firstly click on blow dropdown option, it will show you option list. at the same way click on above gallary menu where dropdown option appear. Now see the changes. above dropdown option hide under the below dropdown option. I need to show above dropdown option list always at front. http://jsfiddle.net/j4vkxop5/

Comment: Thanks you so much for the better solution. I am looking forward to achieve it.